# Return a row even if no record is found in where in() MySql

Tags: mysql, sql, database, row, where-in

```
select id from table where email in (a,b,c);
```

I do not have an id for b, so it returns:

> 1
>   3

But I want it to return

> 1
>   null 
>   3

I do not want to use joins.
Thank you!

Comment: *I do not want to use joins* - **why not??**

Comment: you can used  `select if(email in (a,b,c),id,null) from table`

Comment: Is the use of a keyboard acceptable? What about electricity? Please be specific.

Comment: LOL... @Strawberry both are acceptable. Now give me the answer.

Comment: @AdilKhan Use joins

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1):

The schema of your tables is not quite clear, but having table with attributes email and id then you probably wants something like this:

```
select tab.id 
from (select 'a' email union all select 'b' union all select 'c') emails
left join tab on emails.email = tab.email
```

[demo](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=2f02f99c52a2c4f010c0f3062953f75d)